# WIX: detect if visual studio 2013 installed

Tags: wix, visual-studio-2013

All we know about this charming way of detection Visual Studio path and others: [wixvsextension](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixvsextension.html)

Also we know that VS2013 is supported in latest WIX builds.
But Visual Studio 2013 was released and I cannot find any documentation about **VS2013_ROOT_FOLDER** and **VS2013_IDE_VWD_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED**.

Are they implemented but not documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they're implemented but not documented. That's a bug.